# Display full SQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a table: "downloads", with 4 columns: "id", "filename", "dldate" and "count".

I want to print the whole live table in PHP like this (and every time I add a new row in my database, I want this to automatic update and add a new row here:

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | filename   | dldate     |  count             |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | file1.exe  | 12.12.2012 |   322              |
| 2    | file2.exe  | 13.12.2012 |   112              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

I have been trying myself:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM downloads") or die(mysql_error());
Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { Print "<tr>";

    Print "<th>1:</th> <td>".$info['SELECT * FROM downloads'] . " </td></tr>";

}
Print "</table>";
?>
```

I need help. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `$info['columnName']` you do that for the columns you want from the db an concatenate them

Comment: @Mihai uhm huh? I didn't quite understand that..

Comment: @Mihai Soo.. $info['id, filename, dldate, count']

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer that you want:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border cellpadding=3>";

function do_the_query($id_higher_than) {
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM downloads WHERE id > ".$id_higher_than) or die(mysql_error());
  return mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

// headers
$info = do_the_query(-1);
echo "<tr>"
foreach ($info as $col_name => $col_value) {
  echo "<td>".$col_name."</td>"
}
echo "</tr>"

// records
while(1) { // yeah, its an infinite loop
  echo "<tr>"
  foreach ($info as $col_name => $col_value) {
    echo "<td>".$col_value."</td>"
  }
  echo "</tr>"
  flush(); // this will force PHP to send the output to your browser

  // check for new records
  sleep(1);
  $info = do_the_query($info["id"]);
}

// I won't put a "</table>" because this will never happen

?>
```

**The long answer that you doesn't want (but is what I would do):**

Web programming is very different of desktop programming. In a desktop programming world, your application runs indefinitely until the user closes it. So you have a infinite loop running in a process that is killed when the user press a button or somewhat to closes the app.

In a web programming world your app must end quickly, in few ms. The lifecycle is very short. You read the database, get the answer, format, output them and get off - close the app. If the user want to get more updated data, he needs to manually refresh (like by pressing F5). To be more friendly, you can refresh automatically, using JS to do that - for more advanced and good experience, you can refresh using an Ajax technique and use JS to update the HTML.

Because of this nature, all the tools of the web programming world are designed with "hurry to close" mindset. The "mysql_query" function, for instance, executes the query and get out.

What you processes with "my_sql_fetch_array" is just a buffer of a thing that already happened - you won't are in a "livestream" connection with the db. Also, you probably won't see anything on the screen, because the PHP puts all your output (of "Print", "echo", etc) in a variable which is only sended to the browser when you PHP app closes - that's why I put a "flush" call. Also, your PHP will be killed in approximately 5 minutes - because PHP will think that you have a bugged app: a PHP app shouldn't last more than few ms. You can change this by changing the "max-execution-time" directive in php.ini or by calling "set_time_limit" at execution time. This is why "while"/"do..while"/"for" statements are bad words (always prefer "foreach" - so you avoid to fall in infinite loops).

After all this, and assuming that you are using PHP to do web programming (and not a desktop app) please, **don't do that**. This is not how websites are designed.

*PS: I haven't tested the code above (I had write from my head) because I don't program in PHP for more than 2 years and I have not PHP installed. So may contain some syntax errors.*